# Evaluating this limit

Tags: limits

I have a calc 2 final soon and I've gotten the majority of the material down, except this one question on the review sheet. I just don't get how I would approach it.

Evaluate the following Limit:

[image: Evaluate the following Limit:]

EDIT: one more problem I've come across - 
Again evaluating the following limit:
[image]

Comment: It seems to be a sigma calculating problem, not a limit problem

Comment: You have written down no limits.

Comment: The question was to evaluate the limits, and I was given this series. The user below gave me a huge hint which got me the answer.

Comment: Infinite sums and integrals with $\infty$ as the upper limit are limits per definition.

Comment: Don't ask two question within one.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it'd be considered spam if I made two threads back to back.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

$$\cos x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

Comment: You are an amazing person. This isn't the first time you've helped me. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. It's my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's an alternating series, so all you need to do is determine whether the nonalternating part is decreasing to 0.   As you increase n by 1, the numerator gets 2 more copies of $\frac pi 6$.   Meanwhile, the denominator picks up $(2n+2)(2n+1)$.  so you are multiplying by fractions that are smaller and smaller, so this is strictly smaller than a geometric series with a fractional ratio...so you are going to 0,  hense you are convergent.